# i have an error with mysqli database (error 1005)

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `maht_subs` (
`smaht_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
`smaht_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`smaht_mahbert` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`smaht_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`point_smaht` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`number` int(11) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`userlast` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`userid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`mgma_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`password` text,
`useradmin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

when i exc this query

```
create table maht_grades
(
id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
userid int,
smaht_code int,
moaad varchar(50),
date date,
grade_magen varchar(50),
grade_final varchar(50),
mahbert text,
constraint pk45 primary key(id),
constraint fko foreign key(userid) references users(number),
constraint fk13 foreign key(smaht_code) references maht_subs(smaht_code)
);
```

i get this message :

> > ## 1005 - Can't create table `ministry`.`maht_grades` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

i checked the data type from tables users and maht_subs ,
but nothing happen

can anyone help me to fix it ?

Comment: Hint:  The foreign key of one table should be referencing the primary key of another table.

Comment: i did with primary key of another tables

Comment: @marmsaeed The tables you are using do not have a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a foreign key, the column referencing should have the exact same type as the column it references. Change `userid` and `smaht_code` to `int(11)` instead of `int`, and you should be OK.

Comment: i still have this error